# Simple Flask project runs slowly

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting started with Flask, and am finding some odd latency problems.

The Flask code is the simplest possible 'Hello World!' as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and it's installed on a remote Ubuntu 18 server using a VM and Gunicorn, as follows:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --reload
```

I am using the Python 'requests' library to call the server under Windows 10, as follows:

```
import requests, time

url = 'http://vps.XXXXX.ssdhosts.com.au:5000/'

t0 = time.time()
response = requests.get(url)                       
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print("Simple get request took " , total)
```

The issue is that the time to call the remote function always takes between 0.7s and 1s, which seems slow for such a simple function. My impression from reading about similar deployments is that this call should be much faster.

Can this function be speeded up?

I have tried:

- hard-coding the IP address
- disabling IPv6
- setting threaded=True in app.run()
- calling the web address from a browser

None of these make any difference.

In addition, the server is in Australia while I am in the UK. Would this cause a slow-down?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, going halfway around the world (especially to Australia, as I understand) will cause latency. Just simply using Speedtest.net from here in Finland says there's 330 ms of latency to Sydney, 5 ms to my nearest test server.

I replicated your steps on a Digital Ocean machine in Amsterdam:

```sh
~# cd $(mktemp -d)
/tmp/tmp.4ahzWvNRpX# python3.5 -m venv venv
/tmp/tmp.4ahzWvNRpX# source venv/bin/activate
(venv) /tmp/tmp.4ahzWvNRpX# pip install flask gunicorn
(venv) /tmp/tmp.4ahzWvNRpX# cat > app.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
(venv) /tmp/tmp.4ahzWvNRpX# gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --reload
```

and on my Mac, with the same test code as yours, I get an entirely tolerable 60msec.

```sh
~/Desktop $ python3 x.py
Simple get request took  0.06290006637573242
~/Desktop $ python3 x.py
Simple get request took  0.06206989288330078
~/Desktop $ python3 x.py
Simple get request took  0.0690619945526123
~/Desktop $ python3 x.py
Simple get request took  0.06926107406616211
~/Desktop $
```

With the `uwsgi` application server (`uwsgi --http :5000 --master --wsgi app:app`) results are similar (`uwsgi` itself reports it takes less than 1 msec to actually get a response from the code), but I assume they'd be better with a larger concurrency scale.

My best guess is your results area the compound effect of possibly a slow VPS *and* going around the world.

Comment: That makes sense. Pinging the IP address of my server shows an average round trip of about 350ms. So I'm guessing there is nothing wrong with the setup.

Answer (score 1):

did you try giving gunicorn more than one worker?

add a "-w 2" in gunicorn's CLI:

`gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --reload`

...5 months later but hopefully this might helpful to other...